# Motion goes active (exited) after a few minutes

Tags: camera, motion

*I'm not a native english speaker, just in case... if you don't understand something please ask me.*

I installed motion in my Raspberry pi B+ to use a web camera, when I run:

```
sudo service motion start
```

It works, and I can see my camera in the port **8081**, but... after a few minutes the service goes **active (exited)** and I can't see my camera anymore.

I checked that with:

```
sudo service motion status
```

But then I restart it with:

```
sudo service motion restart
```

And it works again, but just for a few minutes.

¿Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'd suggest starting it from the command line instead of systemd and see if it reports any errors at the shell window.

Comment: Thank you @Kolban if I start it with

<code>sudo /usr/bin/motion</code>

It works, but I have to do this first:

<code>sudo service motion stop</code>

Now... How can I make it start on boot in this way...?

Comment: See the following video about starting a program at boot time.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEuViHanjKI

Use this or other procedures to start an arbitrary program at boot time.  So ... ignore the fact that we are starting motion ... and start studying about how to start an arbitrary program at boot and we should be good

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem, as it will let others know that it is a valid solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your command run at boot I recommend that you add it to the `/etc/etc.local` file which executes all commands inside of it on boot

1. Open the `/etc/rc.local` file by using the following command:

   ```
   Sudo nano /etc/rc.local
   ```
2. Enter the command that you wish to execute:

   ```
   sudo service motion start &
   ```

Note: you have to put the command before the last line in /etc/rc.local that contains: `exit 0`

3. Reboot your Pi